# Generate random normal data and then categorise

Tags: r, normal-distribution, r-factor

Here is the question/prompt

1. For this, generate a vector of 1000 values that are randomly drawn from a normal distribution with a mean of 50 and a standard deviation of 10. Label this additional column "RGENDER".
2. Change RGender so that values of less than 50 are labelled Male and values of 50 or more are labelled Female. When using the levels() for value$RGENDER you should see "Female"and "Male".**

For 1. I have:

```
stats$RGENDER <- rnorm(1000, 50 ,10)
```

And for 2. I was trying:

```
stats1$RGENDER <- factor(stats$RGENDER, levels=c(<50, >50), 
                                                labels=c("Male", "Female"))
```

I keep getting an error message,

`Error: unexpected '<' in "stats$RGENDER <- factor(stats$RGENDER, levels=c(<"`

and am not sure what to do. Does anyone know if this is the completely wrong function or if I'm just making an error in writing the function?

Comment: The `levels` argument of `factor()` doesn't work the way you think it does.  Check out `ifelse`.

Comment: so should I be using a different argument in replacement of levels Ben?

Comment: If you look at `?factor` you will see that it takes argument such that it is `a vector of data, usually taking a small number of distinct values.`. You have passed the continuous vector. You need to categorise this before or in the `factor` call.

Answer (score 2):

```
stats <- data.frame(RGENDER=rep(NA,1000))  # Cannot use `$<-` unless df exists
stats$RGENDER <- rnorm(1000, 50 ,10) 
stats$RGENDER <- factor(stats$RGENDER >50, levels=c('TRUE','FALSE'), 
                                                 labels=c("Male", "Female"))
```

Needed to set the 'levels' so they matched what would be returned from a logical operator.

```
>  table(stats$RGENDER)

  Male Female 
   513    487
```